# pickadate.js min 3 days, excluding weekends

Tags: jquery, pickadate

I'm using pickadate.js in a form.

My requirements are:

- All weekends excluded
- Minimum selected date is to be 3 **working days** from today

My code:

`var disabledDates = [1,7,{from:true, to: 2}];
$("#myDate').pickadate({
    disable: disableDates,
    min: 2
});`

Disabling days 1 & 7 works fine, and the 3 day minimum works fine, EXCEPT when the 3 day minimum occurs over the weekend.

eg.If today is Friday, you can select Monday. The expected result would be if Today is Friday: Sat, Sun, Mon & Tues should be disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing using jQuery UI:

```
setMinDate: function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();

    return day <= 2 ? 3 : 5;
},

setPicker: function () {
    var datePicker = $("#datePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d-M-yy",
        minDate: setMinDate()
    });
}
```

The above JavaScript is the part of my main script.